# Remove the outer list of a double list

Tags: python, list

Let's say i have a list that consist of:

```
[['a','b','c','d']]
```

Is there an easy way to remove the outer list so the output would be

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

I figured something like pop, but that remove the element, and i just want to remove the outer list.

I know i could iterate over the double list and append the elements to a new list, and the problem would be solved, but im not happy with that solution, i want a smoother one with cleaner code.

Comment: "I figured something like pop, but that remove the element, and i just want to remove the outer list." what would be the difference?

Comment: While it's probably not useful for most cases, there is a way to *directly* rewrite the existing `list` without the nesting, rather than extracting it, so other references to the `list` are modified as well. `mylist[:] = mylist[0]` would replace the contents of `mylist` with the contents of the nested list without changing the identity of `mylist`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use unpacking:

```
[new_list] = [['a','b','c','d']]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

Comment: what happens if there is more than one item in the list?

Comment: @Rajez it depends on what the OP is trying to achieve. `itertools` works for nested lists; however, if the OP just has a single list, this one of the "cleanest" solutions.

Comment: You can use with itertools.chain https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Comment: @Ajax1234 Hmm yes, It is neat for single list..